Как заполнить плоскость кирпичной текстурой?
Как наложить текстуру кирпича на стену, чтобы учитывались проёмы?
Кирпичи сделал, применил массив по х и у. Можно ли использовать её для наложения?



https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html

А то что вы сделали - это не текстура, а геометрия. Можете и ей стенку оформить, конечно, сдвинув каждый второй ряд на полкирпича и руками повырезав проемы.

Вы можете достаточно просто создать кирпичную стену используя шейдеры. Для более реалистичного вида придется доработать.

Выбирете объект сцены
Добавьте материал
Передите в окно с Shader Editor (редактор шейдеров)



Добавьте новую ноду (Texture -> Brick Texture)
Выберите подходящие цвета и другие параметры (размеры кирпича)
Соедините вывод ноды с Base Color в Principled BSDF


Результат будет примерно такой:

Конечно, для реализма не хватает глубины и шереховатости, это все тоже можно настроить, при желании.
